# How to return XML data from Web Service to XForms page

Tags: xml, web-services, xforms, orbeon

I have a web service, which reads an xml document from a database (in the db it is stored as a string), and sends it to an xforms page. I want to replace the instance with this xml.
Of course, if I send is as string, xforms won't recognize it as an xml document.
Is there a way to send it as an XML document (in C# I found an XMLDocument class, but in java..?), or somehow tell xforms to process it as an xml-instance?

I'm using axis2 for building web services, and Orbeon for Xforms. Maybe the solution is about orbeon's converter (or serializer?) processor, but I'm not sure, what should I do with them...

Thanks!

Comment: how are you calling your code that generates the XML? Are you using an `<xforms:submission>`? If not, what are you using?

Comment: @avernet I use submission to invoke the web service:
`<xforms:submission id="getit"
    ref="instance('getit-instance')"
    replace="instance"
    method="post" 
    mediatype="text/xml" 
    instance="getitresults-instance"
    action="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/GetTasks/getIt"
/>`
The WS reads the xml (string) from the database, and sends is back to the xforms.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I needed to use the `saxon:parse()` function.
Details here: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/orbeon-forms-faq/faq-other